# Angular controller repeating the same if statement

Tags: angularjs

All of the controllers in my app share a dependency on a data provider type service I created. This service consists of functions to retrieve various bits of data, and almost all of these methods allow for an optional parameter. The ability to enter in this optional parameter is role based. The problem is my controllers are now full of code similar to:

```
// Initializing controller.
dataservice.getRole().then(function(role) { $scope.isAdmin = role.isAdmin; });

// After a button press or some other event.
if($scope.isAdmin) {
    dataservice.getData($scope.param1, $scope.param2, $scope.optionalText);
} else {
    dataservice.getData($scope.param1, $scope.param2);
}
```

It seems a code smell to me that I have to keep repeating this code throughout the controllers, but I can't think of a way to construct my controllers where I don't have to.

Comment: Put the data in services/factories. They are singletons, meaning the same instance is shared across all controllers.

Comment: @pixelbits Yours is the solution I went with. I ended up creating a service to house just the user data and anything that needed to either set it or read it got that service as a dependency. I added it as a dependency on the dataservice object so it could read out from it there, and I added it onto my controller that needed to set it. Worked beautifully. If you write your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I've realized that: [Controller Inheritance](http://williamverdolini.github.io/2014/01/20/discitur-appinit_en#controller-inheritance).

Basically:

1. Create your service (factory) with your Base Controller logic and
   return the Constructor ([example](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/blob/master/app/modules/main/DisciturBaseCtrl.js))
2. Use [$injector.invoke](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/%24injector) in your derived Class (to implement your
   base controller) in order to enrich the actual controller $scope
   ([example](https://github.com/williamverdolini/discitur-web/blob/master/app/modules/lesson/LessonSideBarCtrl.js))

There's no an official "angular way" to implement this features, but I hope the angular team will work on it